# why we initialize array differently in php, javascript and etc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my question why we initialize array in different ways.

as i initialize array in php like `array();` 
and in javascript in different way.

please anyone explain difference between array() and Array().

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking why different languages are different, then... because they're different languages?

Comment: Well, they're different languages, and their designers can pick whatever existing style they like to do it - or come up with a new one, as they please. Not very relevant to the question but in PHP you can also initialize an (empty) array with `[]`, just like in Javascript.

Comment: Why in English the Yes is Yes  and in French is Oui and in Italian is Si ??????  this is a  great mystery

Comment: you can also initiate an array in both languages by using $name/name = []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer is that they are completely different languages and, just as different spoken languages have different grammar and vocabularies from each other, so do programming languages.

Beyond that, every programming language has to have some sort of runtime or compiler that understands the syntax, data structures, processing model, etc. And, each of those environments are free to implement those details as they see fit. This means that how an Array is internalized can be quite different between languages. But, to the programmer, we don't really need (or care) to know those implementation details.

Comment: but someone ask me this question and i said i don't know because i think in programming language everything with a reason. so i asked.

Comment: The reasons come down to what the language designer wanted to use. There could be various reasons why this or that was selected, but in the end, it was just a choice that someone made.

Comment: It can be 100% annoying at times when you switch between languages and can't understand why your array declaration keeps throwing an error

Comment: @MatthewLagerwey For me, it's comment syntax!